# Local library linking in Makefile

Tags: c, makefile, fftw

I have precompiled fftw3 libraries in an external_libs directory that I'm trying to link to with a custom Makefile, but when I ldd the .so the Makefile produces it is pointing to a .so in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. How can I modify my Makefile so that it forces the .so to use the libraries I point it to?

Here's my Makefile

```
include config.h

# Define the executable file
MAIN = libmyfftw
MAINC = LIBMYFFTW

# Define the path
VPATH = ../../src/fftw

# Define the source and object files
SRCS := $(shell find $(VPATH) -name '*.c')
OBJS = $(SRCS:.c=.o)

# Define import and export flags
IMPORTFLAGS = 
EXPORTFLAGS = -DEXPORT_$(MAINC)

# Define any directories containing header files other than /usr/include
INCLUDES = -I$(INCDIR)

# Define library paths in addition to /usr/lib
LFLAGS = -L./ -L../../external_libs/linux/fftw

# Define libraries to link into the executable
ILIBS = -lfftw3_omp -lfftw3 -lfftw3f_omp -lfftw3f -lutils

# Define all programs to build
PROGS = $(MAIN).$(SHLE)

all: $(PROGS)
    @echo "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo $(MAIN) has been compiled successfully
    @echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"

$(MAIN).$(SHLE): $(OBJS)
    $(LN) -o $(MAIN).$(SHLE) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) $(ILIBS) $(LIBS)

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDES) -c $< -o $@

install: $(PROGS)
    @-cp $(PROGS) $(BINDIR)
    @echo "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Finished $(MAIN) make install"
    @echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"

clean:
    @-rm $(PROGS) $(OBJS)
    @echo "\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
    @echo "Finished $(MAIN) make clean"
    @echo "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
```

My external_libs/linux/fftw directory holds libfftw3.a, libfftw3f.a, libfftw3f_omp.so, and libfftw3_omp.so. My config.h is pretty basic. I think the only relevant line from it is `LIBS = -lm -lc -lz`. The output of `ldd libmyfftw.so` is

```
ldd libmyfftw.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc1a74a000)
    libfftw3_omp.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3_omp.so.3 (0x00007fd5710d3000)
    libfftw3f_omp.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f_omp.so.3 (0x00007fd570ecc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fd570b2e000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fd57073d000)
    libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fd57050e000)
    libfftw3.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3.so.3 (0x00007fd57010c000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fd56feed000)
    libfftw3f.so.3 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libfftw3f.so.3 (0x00007fd56fae0000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fd571905000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fd56f8dc000)
```

Where I would expect the fftw .so's to look something like this

```
libfftw3_omp.so => /path/to/external_libs/linux/fftw/libfftw3_omp.so (0x00007fd5710d3000)
```

But that's obviously not the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I always wonder why people write makefiles by hand in the 21st century. It is so human unfriendly. I would use IDE with a decent build system (like eclipse) or use CMAKE

Comment: @0___________ 1) Because you have no enough control on the process; there is too much magic involved. 2) Automatic builds can commonly only produce one target. My Makefiles can have up to 20 targets.

Comment: Did you try to add the library with your local path directly on the command line, for example after all object files?

Comment: @thebusybee CMAKE makes it much easier

Comment: @0___________ 3) CMake does not know my target systems.